# Factory Girl Error with Nested Attributes & Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot

I have a `Company` model that `has_many` `Users` that `belongs_to` the `Company`. I also have a callback in the `Company` model that calls an external service that I'd like to avoid. I am trying to setup FactoryGirl with the linter, but it keeps throwing errors.

Here's how the controller looks:

```
class CompanyController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def new
    @company = Company.new
    @user = @company.users.build
  end

  def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)
    @user = @company.users.first
    ...
  end

  ...
end
```

The controller works fine on localhost and in production, so there's no problem necessarily with the code functioning - it's a testing issue that I'm having.

I am trying to create a factory along these lines:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do
    name Faker::Company.name
    association :user, strategy: :build
    before(:create) do |company|
      company.class.skip_callback(:create, :before, :my_callback)
    end
  end

  factory :user do
    email Faker::Internet.email
    password "password"
    password_confirmation "password
  end
end
```

The problem is that I get an error saying that a `company must exist` for the user since `belongs_to` is required and an error for company saying `undefined method user=` since I'm trying to build multiple users. I have also tried many other variations of this that end up not skipping the callback (such as creating the company in the user factory).

I'm hoping someone knows how to build a factory in a way that's compatible with this type of controller setup or if there's a different way I should be building the controller without nested attributes?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I was going to just add an comment but I don't have enough reputation for that.

You didn't show your models and your db tables, but I suppose your `users` table has a `company_id` field and the `Company` model has the line `has_many :users`.

That's how I would use factory girl in this situation:

User factory:

```
  factory :user do
    email Faker::Internet.email
    password "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
    company
  end
```

Company factory:

```
 factory :company do
    name Faker::Company.name
 end
```

Then in the test you want to create multiple users, right?

```
company = create(:company)
number_of_users = 5
create_list(:user, number_of_users, company: company)
```

That way all the users you create will be associated to the same company.